# Firebase error When adding data from React. This document does not exist, it will not appear in queries or snapshots

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Why am I getting this error in firebase the about person document:

> This document does not exist, it will not appear in queries or snapshots.

What I'm trying to do is add a subcollection called "postingJobs" with a document in side it,  to a person document that already exists.

I think the problem is with this line:

```
const get = await setDoc(doc(collection(doc(collection(database, "persons")), "postingJobs"), getCurrentDateTimeString()), {
```

anyone know what I need to change?

```
const addPost = async (e) => {
    try {

        const get = await setDoc(doc(collection(doc(collection(database, "persons")), "postingJobs"), getCurrentDateTimeString()), {
            identityUserPublishId: userId,
            createdAt: serverTimestamp()
        });
        return true;

    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: The `postingJobs` in your code fragments is a document ID. It is **not** a collection name. --- If that doesn't explain the problem, where exactly in your code does the error come from? The stack trace should tell you that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means the document doesn't exist, and by default it will through an error, to fix it make sure the document exist first then add some code to create it if it doesn't exist.

If it exists when you open your firebase, then make sure that you have set up the config correctly in your project, and make sure your FireStore Rules allow it to add data.

Comment: Thank you, but the rules are ok, and while the person document exists, the postingJobs collection is being created with a new document inside of it. Is this an issue?

Comment: I think you want to update an existing document within the `postingJobs` collection under a persons document rather than creating a new document every time, you'd need to modify the code to reference the specific existing document in the `postingJobs` collection instead of generating a new document ID each time.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to add a new postingjob document, not to updtate one.

Comment: If this is the case your code is correct but make sure that the `getCurrentDateTimeString()` and `serverTimestamp()` exists. if they exist, I can't help you without you providing more info, because the code is correct.